# Is blogging , affiliate marketing , E-commerce etc are the fields of Computer Science

Tags: self-learning, programming, secondary-education, active-learning

**Question Background:**

I am CS students . Now a day lot of peoples are learning and earning through ->  blogging , affiliate marketing , E-commerce etc . And also provides these type of services !

**Question in Detail :**

**Part 1:**
I want to know that these services or whatever fields are included in computer science or not . why ?

**part 2:**
And i also want to know that there is lot of software development fields like software development , app dev. , web dev. etc are included in cs or not .

**Question Summary:**
How i determined that , which skill or subject i am learning is part or field or computer science or not , means on which bases i know that i determined it . for example i am learning game development then how i know that is it part of computer science or not ?

Comment: Recommend you read the Wikipedia article on Computer Science, esp., the section on what fields it includes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science#Fields

Comment: Maybe you're looking for lists such as these https://learntocodewith.me/posts/tech-skills-in-demand/ ?

Comment: no i don't  need list @Rusi

Comment: The fields you are asking about require the use of computers & the internet, they are applications. They are not required for the functioning of computers. The fields you mention could be regarded as being similar to online banking & it is not a field of computer science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same difference between auto manufacturing and auto racing.

Blogging, affiliate marketing, E-commerce etc. relate to computer science because computer science creates their engines. But it doesn't create their content.

The site we're using right now exists because some computer scientist developers created the web service that lets us write content for it. We're not doing computer science when we post here. We're just using it. That's the difference. Contributing content is not computer science.

Comment: and what about computer graphics designing ?

Comment: @Hamza creating GIMP is CS. Using GIMP is not.

Comment: you want to say Software engineering  is  part of cs , but why it is ?

Comment: @hamza because words mean things.

Comment: i don't understand this sentence meaning . tell me in simple words

Comment: To be fair, software eng. = CS is not exactly uncontroversial. (just try asking a prog question on CS-SE, you'll quickly find out!) Personally I'd say prog ≠ CS is evidence of an insane world. Statistically tho', odds stacked against the crazy being yours truly !

Comment: @Rusi Computer Scientists, Software Engineers, & Developers are all sub sets of Programmers. Users are not.

Comment: «CS-ists, SE-ists & devs ⊆ Programmers» . In a sane world yeah. In our world just head over to [CS-SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), try asking a programming question and see if it remains open for 24 hours!  They say it clearly enough "Programming questions are off topic here" https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. More seriously there are PhDs in CS who can't write a line of code to save their lives. **And contribute to educating the next gen CS-ists in hi-falutin institutions.**

Comment: @Rusi and there are mathematicians who can’t balance a checkbook. Doesn’t mean addition and subtraction aren’t part of mathematics.

Comment: @candied_orange : i think Is blogging , affiliate marketing , E-commerce is part of IT

Answer (score 6):

None of those are computer science, no.  It's hard to say what computer science *is* because it is a bit of a historical mish-mash, but blogging, e-commerce, and affiliate marketing are not anywhere in this field.

Game programming intersects with CS, however.

Computer Science is, depending on who you ask, programming (think software engineers), computer hardware, architecture and networks (think I.T., network people, or the folks who design the next processor Intel is going to put out), or theory associated with computation (think mathematicians).

As you can see, marketing, which is its own completely separate field, is nowhere near any of those categories.

Comment: and what about computer graphics designing ?

Comment: @Hamza That is more akin to art than to engineering, though there are potential areas of overlap in that field.

Answer (score 1):

Computer Science was started by mathematicians, Alan Turing being the prime example. It quickly merged with engineering as a way to create the machines that were being theorized.

If the topic in question can be accomplished without having to concern yourself with coding or hardware, it probably doesn't fall under the umbrella of computer science.

Comment: i think Is blogging , affiliate marketing , E-commerce  part of it !!?

Comment: Then not, those topics do not satisfy the definition of computer science. They are not concerned with how the computer works, but rather how it is used.

Comment: 1) then what is definition of computer science to find out which fields or something else is part of computer science or not ?                                                                      (2)  then these (blogging , affiliate marketing , E-commerce ) is part of information technology ?